# How to check if associated object exists in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There is the following code in Comments controller:

```
  def create
    current_user.comments.create!(place: current_place, content: params[:content])
    render json: encode_result
  end

  private
    def current_place
      Place.find(params[:place_id])
    end
```

This code creates a new comment for a current user and a current place; if the current place doesn't exist than this code throws exception RecordNotFound. I can send 'place_id' instead of 'place' for 'create' method, but I need to check if place exists before creating a new comment. Please, tell me, is my solution good or there is any better way? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is doing what it's supposed to do. Your code is perfect as it's written now. You specifically want to halt execution if a specified record doesn't exist. All you need to do is handle the exception.

You can do this for your entire controller with [`rescue_from`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html), or your entire application by placing `rescue_from` in your `ApplicationController`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.........

```
 def create
current_user.comments.create!(place: current_place, content: params[:content]) if current_place
    render json: encode_result
  end

  private
    def current_place
      Place.find(params[:place_id])
    end
```

Comment: This will call the same query twice one for if condition and second one when assigning place: current_place. so this is not a optimal solution. Try to make it optimal i am voting for it